# How to resize the font in html using @media query for particular width range?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to resize the font in HTML using `@media query` only when the width size will be in the range of 769px to 991px

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .most-1 h5 {
        font-size: 5vm;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="most-1">
    <h5>Hello World!</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: there is nothing called `vm` in css you can use `vw` or `vh`

Comment: I am going to vote to close this on the grounds of typographical error. As others have stated there is no vm unit it is `vw` or `vh`.

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing called `vm` in css you can use `vw` or `vh`

you can check this link for the css units https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

check below example...

```css
.most-1 h5 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 269px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .most-1 h5 {
        font-size: 1vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="most-1">
    <h5>Hello World!</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

vmax and vmin we have in unit (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
If you need you can specify custom font size to h1 tag, it is not mandatory

```
.most-1 h5 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 269px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .most-1 h5 {
        font-size: 1vw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vmax and vmin we have in unit. [sample unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

[sample code here](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/JxPLNZ)

Here using px unit.

```
font-size: 12px;
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it is useful , Can be done using css also.
The text size can be set with a vw unit, which means the "viewport width".
That way the text size will follow the size of the browser window:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:10vw;">Responsive Text</h1>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the text size scales.</p>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Use the "vw" unit when sizing the text. 10vw will set the size to 10% of the viewport width.</p>

<p>Viewport is the browser window size. 1vw = 1% of viewport width. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw is 0.5cm.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[example from w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp)